# Groovy's MarkupBuilder exception on generating "id" XML tag

Tags: java, xml, grails, groovy, markupbuilder

I'm trying to construct a XML feed, and Groovy's MarkupBuilder is giving me headaches:

```
 def newsstandFeed(def id) {
    def publication = Publication.get(id)
    def issues = issueService.getActiveIssuesForPublication(publication)
    def updateDate = DateUtil.getRFC3339DateString(publication.lastIssueUpdate)

    def writer = new StringWriter()
    writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    xml.feed('xmlns':"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", 'xmlns:news':"http://itunes.apple.com/2011/Newsstand") {
        updated("${updateDate}")
        issues.each { issue ->
            entry {
                id (issue.id)
                updated("${DateUtil.getRFC3339DateString(issue.lastUpdated)}")
                published("${DateUtil.getRFC3339DateString(issue.releaseDate)}")
                summary(issue.summary)
                "news:cover_art_icons" {
                    "news:cover_art_icon" (size:"SOURCE", src:"${issue.cover.remotePath}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return writer.toString()
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Class groovy.lang.MissingMethodException 
No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [CYB_001] Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

"CYB_001" is the first "id" attribute.

If I rename "id" it to "ids" or anything else, it works, and returns a proper XML document:

```
            ....
            issues.each { issue ->
            entry {
                ids ("${issue.id}")
                ...
```

Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can work around the problem?

The environment is Grails 2.1.1 (so Groovy 1.8, I assume)

Comment: Removing the quotes didn't work, btw:

id (issue.id) - same exception

Comment: Why would you not just use the feeds plugin? http://grails.org/Feeds+Plugin

Comment: What comes before this code? Can you post the whole method block?

Comment: Good point. In fact I'm already using it for some RSS feed (same content, just different format), but I had trouble getting it to output an atom feed that conforms to Apple's spec https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/NewsstandAtomFeedSpecification.pdf

Comment: Will P - thanks! Actually, I have a local variable id - if I rename it, it works, duh. ;-) (Put your comment in an answer and I will accept it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your XML builder is trying to reference some **String** variable in the environment. Since groovy builder intercept missing method calls, if they find a reference they will try to apply to it. The following code can reproduce your error:

```
def id = ""

new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder().xml {
  id "90"
}
```

And the following is fine:

```
def ids = ""

new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder().xml {
  id "90"
}
```

Renaming your `id` variable should do the trick

---

**Update:**

An alternative way to use a tag with same name as a variable in the scope is with a (ugly) GString:

```
def id = ""

new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder().xml {
  "${'id'}" "90"
}
```

Comment: Glad I found this answer - had been running into the same thing.  In my case, I had a parameter ("username") to the method building the XML that was identical to the tag ("username").   Changing my parameter to "usernameParam" fixed it.

Comment: Note that even if you had

def id = ""

new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder().xml {
  "id" "90"
}

it would still have a collision. I found this using JsonBuilder instead of MarkupBuilder

Answer (score 0):

run into the same situation and qualify it with the builder solved the problem for me.

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
    def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    builder.executions() {
        project.scalaVersions.each { scalaVersion ->
            def scalaMajorVer = '_' + scalaVersion.split('\\.')[0..1].join('.')
            def artifactIdStr = publication.artifactId.replaceAll(/_[0-9.]+$/, '') + scalaMajorVer

            execution() {
                builder.id(artifactIdStr) // qualify with builder to avoid collision
                phase('deploy')
                goals() { goal('deploy-file') }
                configuration() {
                    groupId(publication.groupId)
                    artifactId(artifactIdStr)
                    builder.version(project.version) // ditto.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```